# modifiy first row for each section of my tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i would modify the first row on each section (modify font size, color, aligment).
I've think something like this:

```
    NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    if (sectionRows == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = cellDetail;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    } else {
cell.textLabel.text = cellDetail;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellValue;
}
```

but this don't make the magic:D
Please let me know if it's better to open another topic or we can continue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on-the-fly as the table is rendered.  See [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)'s `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.  This is invoked before the cell is drawn.  You can make customizations to the cell here.

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

Comment: thank's d11wtq, i'm going to check apple doc of this delegate right now.

Comment: i've modify my code passing in titleForHeaderInSection the first index of my array

Answer (score 0):

To get the row number of the indexPath, just use `indexPath.row`, and take it from there. So replace that first line with:

```
NSInteger sectionRows = [indexPath row];
```

Comment: thank's, i've try it but [indexPath row] don't give me every time the right 1 row of each section, i don't know why. i'll debug this case